Symmetric keys obtained by both parties from their DH shared secret
I have this Diffie-Hellman construction:
Capital denotes a public key, lower-case denotes a private key.
We have DH modulus M (a 3070-bit prime integer), where M-1 is exactly divisible by a 320-bit prime integer Q. We also have a 3070-bit DH generator: G = 2^( (M-1) / Q) mod M.
Alice and Bob both have M and G, and each generate their own 320-bit private key, a and b, from a good pseudorandom source, like /dev/urandom.
Alice and Bob both generate their own public key:
Alice: A = G^a mod M
Bob: B = G^b mod M
They send each other their public keys securely over a central server that they can individually talk to securely. This part is irrelevant to my question, we just assume it works.
Alice and Bob now compute a DH shared secret:
Alice: X = B^a mod M
Bob: X = A^b mod M
Now they want to use the shared secret to send each other an encrypted text message, without the server being able to decrypt it:
They both obtain a symmetric session key pair (KAB, KBA) from the shared secret: KAB = first 32 bytes of X, KBA = next 32 bytes of X.
KAB is to be used by Alice to encrypt stuff she sends to Bob. Bob will use KAB to receive and decrypt it. It reads "key-alice-to-bob".
KBA is to be used by Bob to encrypt stuff he sends to Alice. Alice will use KBA to receive and decrypt it. It reads "key-bob-to-alice".
Alice wants to send a message to Bob. She generates a one-time-use 32-byte key K from /dev/urandom and encrypts it using ChaCha20, using KAB as the ChaCha key. This yields the encrypted key KB. She then encrypts her text message using K as the ChaCha key.
Bob uses KAB as a ChaCha key to decrypt KB, obtaining the one-time use key K, which Alice enciphered her text message with. He then uses the obtained key K in a second call to ChaCha, to reveal Alice's text message.
If Bob wants to send a text message to Alice, he does similarly using "key-bob-to-alice", which is KBA, and Alice does similarly as Bob to receive it.
My question here is, if both Alice and Bob are simply clients participating in a chatroom, which is maintained by the central server, and a chatroom can have many guests in it, each with their own shared secrets (and symmetric key pairs) between each other, how do they know when to use KAB and when to use KBA when sending a message to the chatroom?
If we come up with a simple scheme that says "The client always uses KAB to send, and always uses KBA to receive text messages", that ends up not working because the receiving client has to RECEIVE with KAB, if the other client sent its message with KAB. I just don't get it. How do the clients know which of the 2 session keys (KAB,KBA) to use?
EDIT: I have this part in my construction, which always confused me, and I don't know if it has anything to do with this:
On Alice's side:
KAB = least significant 32 bytes of X, KBA = next 32 bytes of X.

On Bob's side:
KBA = least significant 32 bytes of X, KAB = next 32 bytes of X.

On Alice's side, swap KAB with KBA if A < B.
On Bob's side, swap KBA with KAB if A > B.

Does the swapping on both sides after a comparison of the public keys have anything to do with the two sides knowing whether to use KAB or KBA when sending a text message in this scheme?
EDIT 2: I think my confusion comes from the fact that, when Alice and Bob are a client and a server, it's pretty clear who the 2 sides are. But when Alice and Bob are simply clients, implemented by the same software, in a chatroom maintained by the central server, how do the 2 clients know when to use KAB and when to use KBA? Since the same piece of code implements them in the client software, deployed on 2 different machines?
EDIT 3: I had mistaken G for Q in my original writing. Fixed now.

"Alice and Bob now compute a DH shared secret"; subtle point: Alice should also compute $B^{(M-1)/G} \bmod M$ and make sure that it's 1 (and refuse the encryption if it isn't).  If she doesn't, then by selecting values $B$ and seeing how Alice reacts, Eve can find $a \bmod Q$, for small factors $Q$ of $M-1$, which will help Eve recovering $a$ (depending on how many small factors there are)

@poncho Yes, I have this check in my scheme. I just didn't want to make the post longer than it already is. If you know fgrieu, it's him who helped me come up with this scheme. I just don't know how to reach him and ask him.

@poncho Wait, I just noticed I have a mistake where I say what M and G are. The 320-bit prime was Q. G is something entirely different, I will add it to the top of my post now.

@poncho Fixed it now. Could it be possible to have a scheme that simply asks which of the 2 clients joined the room earlier than the other? Maybe the decision whether Alice and Bob should use KAB or KBA for sending and receiving can be made with something like:
If Alice was in the room first, then she gets to use KAB for sending (and Bob using KAB for receiving), and Bob uses KBA for sending and Alice uses KBA for receiving.
If Bob was in the room first, Bob uses KAB for sending and Alice uses KBA for sending.
Do you think this is acceptable?

This is more of an implementation problem then a cryptographic one, they just need to distinguish between them somehow. This can be by who joined first, like you suggested, by lexicographical comparison of the public key, by who has a smaller IP address, by who initiated the communication, etc.

@CommandMaster I see, thanks. I understand now. Can you explain to me something else? In my EDIT 1, it says KAB is the first 32 bytes of the shared secret on Alice's side, but it's the NEXT 32 bytes of the shared secret on Bob's side, and exactly one of them swaps it after a public key comparison. Isn't the shared secret supposed to come out the same on both sides? Why don't we just extract both KAB and KBA on both Alice's and Bob's side from the same parts of the shared secret? Why the public key comparisons and the swapping on one of the sides?
